# Fetching data in a background and sending notification in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, background, background-process

What I want to do is: when my app is running in the background, I want to fetch data from API, every, let's say, 5 minutes. If some data changed I want to send a notification to the user. Is something like that possible in Swift? My problem is that I don't know how to run code in the background. I looked up background fetch but it looks like it was not made for this purpose (I can't be sure it will be fired after x amount of time with this). My app will be mostly user opening it once, setting some settings and then leave it in the background for notifications and never open it again. Any suggestions on what I can use for this purpose? I'd like to avoid creating a backend that will send data to the app, if possible.

Comment: This is intentionally not possible on iOS. You need to push notifications to the app when data is available. You cannot poll this way. It's too hard on the battery. No application is allowed to run indefinitely in the background. Applications are also never promised to be run on a fixed schedule. Applications that the user never interacts with will generally never be run.

Comment: @RobNapier normally I would agree, but lately I have been debugging some apps and noticed that apps like Doordash & Lyft can actually run in the background & make calls to their API's, even if you do not have their app on the screen. I tested it by putting their app in the background & watching the web proxy still make calls. So if it isn't possible, how are they doing it?

Comment: I didn't say you couldn't run anything in the background. You can certainly do that in a number of supported ways. You cannot run *indefinitely* in the background like is being asked here. Lyft also does use push notifications as I've described. They also use location services (which can wake the app up during certain movements, but not on a timer). And it is always tricky to compare what very famous apps do, since sometimes they break explicit rules and Apple doesn't stop them (and sometimes gives explicit waivers), while smaller developers get their apps pulled.

Comment: But if Lyft is connecting the server after a day of not using it (which is what's being asked for here), they're definitely abusing something that is not allowed. Whether Apple will stop them is a different question. (Search for "uber greyball" if you want the most egregious version of this story, and how different developers are treated differently.)